# Time from dbase, Time Zone & Midnight

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have some events in my mysql dbase with tipical date format like YYYY-MM-DD and time 00:00:00.
My SELECT query looks like

```
$STH_1 = $DBH->query("SELECT table_name                        
                         FROM information_schema.tables                        
                        WHERE table_name                        
                         LIKE 'v_c_ei\_9%'"); 
$stmts_1 = array();

foreach($STH_1 as $row_1) { 

$stmts_1[] = sprintf("SELECT *
                      FROM %s 
                     WHERE date='%s'", $row_1['table_name'], $date); 

}

$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1);  
$stmt_1 .= "\nORDER BY time ASC";  

$STH_5_2 = $DBH->query($stmt_1);
```

The date variable is typical date format like YYYY-MM-DD.

F.ex. we have an event with DATE and time 23:30:00 (in dbase all times UTC). And I have one user from different Time Zone (f.ex.+1.00 ). For him, the system must display the event not with DATE and time 23:30:00 but with DATE+1 and time 00:30:00. But at this moment, the system display this event with DATE and time 00:30:00 (changes only time, not date) - maybe course the time is changing after this main dbase SELECT.

All received events to display must be only from one DATE with time from 00:00:00 to23:59:59.

What I must to change (maybe in main SELECT query) to receive correct date and time with correlaction with user Time Zone?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` / `DATE` / `TIME` formats?

Comment: As I wrote, I use Date (in format YYYY-MM-DD) and Time (in format 00:00:00), no TIMESTAMP.

Comment: This information being provided to the user in question via your application?

Answer (score 0):

Since the detail you describe is user-specific logic, you ideally want to leave that formatting until as late as possible. In general, it's good practise to handle UTC dates in your database and in the application logic, and only format them when displaying to the user.

Have you considered using the [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)? You could load the date from your database query into a new instance, and then manipulate the object based on user preferences and the [setTimezone() method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).

Comment: thnks, but .. it's not help me now.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to look at MySQL's [`CONVERT_TZ()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).